# Zoho CRM notification to slack made using WorkFlow Rules without the line "Automated Message posted via Zoho CRM Workflow."

Tags: slack, zoho, zoho-deluge

[The information received at Slack from Zoho Workflow Automation](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5nC68.jpg)

I have created a workflow rule to receive notification whenever a new lead is created. My team don't want to get the last line saying "Automated Message posted via Zoho CRM Workflow." [I know !! :(]

I am not to use thrid party api like zapier or make.com.

Is it possible to create a function in the middle or somewhere, which will wrap the 'Notify via Slack' package and then remove the last line.
[Actions availble to me](https://i.stack.imgur.com/n0iWe.png)

The message to be sent
[Message in 'Notify via Slack` action](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KiWAw.png)